# How to put value on laravel collection?

Tags: php, laravel

How to put value on first element in laravel collection ? Something like that `$collection->put('foo', 1)` but adding value to the first element.

```
Collection {#376
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => array:9 [
      "id" => 83
      "status" => "offline"
      "created_date" => "Oct 31, 2018"
      // add foo => 1 here
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect there's a cleaner way to do this, but this is the best I could come up with at the moment.  You could also use `map` or `transform` with a comparison run on the key value that gets sent to their closures, but that would end up cycling through all elements of the array despite you knowing the specific one you want to target.

```
$collection = collect([
    [
        'id' => 83,
        'status' => 'offline',
        'created_date' => 'Oct 31, 2018'
    ]
]);

$firstKey = $collection->keys()->first();  //This avoids the unreliable assumption that your index is necessarily numeric.
$firstElement = $collection->first();
$modifiedElement = array_merge($firstElement, ['foo1' => 1]);
$collection->put($firstKey, $modifiedElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I used that approach $item = $collection->first(); $item['foo'] = 1; return collect([$item]);

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
$data = Model::all();
$data[0]->foo = 'your data here';
```

Comment: Model::get() gives you an Eloquent\Collection, child of Service\Collections.  But each element therein is a Model object, and not an array.  Model objects have dynamic properties, so you can do what you're doing there.  But the question was for a collection of normal arrays, so this would not work.

Comment: @Claymore Here I am accessing model object with `->` but the user wants the first row data so I added `[0]` index because the data is the array of collection objects so please don't downvote before reading it carefully

Comment: OP's `$collection[0]` is an array, not a Model object.  I didn't downvote you because you code would fail, I did it because your premise doesn't match the question.  Not every use-case for Collections involves Eloquent results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` method to update the collection item as following:

```
$collection = collect([
    [
        'id' => 83,
        'status' => 'offline',
        'created_date' => 'Oct 31, 2018'
    ]
]);

$collection->transform(function($entry, $key) {
    if ($key == 0) {
       $entry['foo'] = 1;
    }
    return $entry;
});
```