# How to insert variable and value on collection laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I'm having trouble put values into collection laravel

I've read this with the same problem but didnt worked on me

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084061/how-to-put-value-on-laravel-collection)

This is my collection

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1348
  #items: array:9 [
    0 => {#1350
      +"id": 532
      +"id_user": "BR001"
      +"name": "Jack"
      +"department": "HR
      +"City": "London"
      +"updated_at": "2021-04-08 15:37:32"
    }
    1 => {#1351
      +"id": 522
      +"id_user": "BR002"
      +"name": "Rose"
      +"department": "IR"
      +"city": "London"
      +"updated_at": "2021-04-08 15:36:19"
    }
    2 => {#1352
      +"id": 532
      +"id_user": "AR023"
      +"name": "Michael"
      +"department": "RnD"
      +"City": "London"
      +"updated_at": "2021-04-08 15:45:43"
    }
```

Expected output

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1348
  #items: array:9 [
    0 => {#1350
      +"id": 532
      +"id_user": "BR001"
      +"name": "Jack"
      +"department": "HR
      +"City": "London"
      +"updated_at": "2021-04-08 15:37:32"
      +"Status": "Single"
    }
    1 => {#1351
      +"id": 522
      +"id_user": "BR002"
      +"name": "Rose"
      +"department": "IR"
      +"city": "London"
      +"updated_at": "2021-04-08 15:36:19"
      +"Status": "Single"
    }
    2 => {#1352
      +"id": 532
      +"id_user": "AR023"
      +"name": "Michael"
      +"department": "RnD"
      +"City": "London"
      +"updated_at": "2021-04-08 15:45:43"
      +"Status": "Single"
    }
```

How to add +"Status": "Single" ?

any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: do you want status as single for all the items in array or is there a condition

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed your collection name as $collection.

You can either use map directly or create a function using macro,

#### Using Map Directly

```
$val = $collection->map(function ($value) {
            $value["status"] = "Single";
            return $value;
        });
dd($val);
```

#### Creating custom function using macro

```
Collection::macro('toAddStatusProperty', function () {
            return $this->map(function ($value, $key) {
                $value["status"] = "Single";
                return $value;
            });
        });

$val = $collection->toAddStatusProperty();
dd($val);
```